# Javascript index variable

Tags: javascript

Working on an index variable to increment thru array values.
I think I have the concept right but there is something, I think
in the syntax, that is keeping the JavaScript from working.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

 body {font-family: arial;}
 </style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ChangeIt()
{
var colors;
colors = new Array("red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "purple");
i=0;
document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[0];

var t = setInterval(function() {
    i=(i>=color.length) ? 0 : i+1;
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
}, 3000);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
This page begins with a red background and
changes the body background to four other colors
after three seconds.<br />

The Javascript
function is set in header section and called
from the body.
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
ChangeIt();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so what you are trying to ask?

Comment: Have a look at Javascript's for loop syntax: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Comment: didn't you get color.length is undefined...it should be colors.length

Comment: Did you try looking for errors in your browser's JavaScript console?

Answer (score 2):

Its simple , while setting i value you are using color instead of colors use,

```
 i=(i>=colors.length) ? 0 : i+1;
```

now it works fine , just checked

Comment: Bharath,

Thanks. One of the answers said" Didn't you get color.length is undefined". Is there a debugger for JavaScript that would alert one to an undefined variable?  Thanks again. Allen in Dallas

Comment: No, In the chrome console you will get something like this "Uncaught ReferenceError: color is not defined "

Answer (score 1):

Replace color.length with colors.length

Answer (score 0):

If you check your precious browser console you'll see:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: color is not defined

it's because you are using `color` instead of `colors`.

Code:

```
function ChangeIt() {
    var colors;
    colors = new Array("red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "purple");
    i = 0;
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[0];

    var t = setInterval(function () {
        i = (i >= colors.length) ? 0 : i + 1;
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
    }, 3000);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/wDC9r/

Answer (score 0):

you forgot "s" in

```
var t = setInterval(function() {
    i=(i>=color.length) ? 0 : i+1;
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
}, 3000);
}
```

just change

```
i=(i>=color.length) ? 0 : i+1;
```

into this

```
i=(i>=colors.length) ? 0 : i+1;
```

.

Answer (score 0):

The main mistake could be that you reference `color.length` when surely you mean `colors.length`.

However, a number of other things about your code could be improved.

- Assign the array to `colors` when you declare it.
- You can use an array literal instead of `new Array()`.
- Declare your variables in one line, making `i` local to `ChangeIt()` but still available to the scope of your interval function.
- Change the "increment `i`" line to something easier to read (e.g., have the assignment of `0` as the "else" in your ternary statement).

Here are the changes:

```
function ChangeIt() {
     var colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "purple"], 
         i = 0,  
         fn = function() {
             i = (i < colors.length) ? i + 1 : 0;
             document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
         },
         t = setInterval(fn, 3000);
     fn(); // To set the background immediately.
};
```